# Google fonts isn't working

Tags: fonts, google-font-api

Google fonts always worked fine for me but yesterday, it stopped working...

I use ctrl + shift+ j and my browser give me reason:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Open Sans" style:normal weight:300 stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTfk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2
```

Google fonts doesn't work in any websites :(

I checked with other computer and browsers too and the result is the same.

Is the problem with my Internet Provider? Can I fix this problem?

Comment: use this https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: Could you share how are you loading it? By CSS or HTML? show us some code And if the URL where you're developing is HTTPS